# LSTM classification problem (Keras) - weird result

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, lstm

I learn the network for classification problem with 3 classes as output. As Input have a series of float numbers (typical history lag is 50)

```
x_test shape: (1663, 7, 1)
[[[17.749]
  [18.366]
  [17.898]
  ...
  [25.287]
  [25.128]
  [24.596]]]

y_train shape: (3879, 3)
y_test shape: (1663, 3)
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

so the y is "hot encoded"

The model:

```
batch_size_to_train = 32
history_lag = 7
epoch_to_train = 100

model = Sequential() 
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)

model.add(LSTM(units=history_lag, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.02))

model.add(LSTM(units = history_lag, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.02))

model.add(LSTM(units = history_lag, return_sequences = True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.02))

model.add(LSTM(units = history_lag))
model.add(Dropout(0.02))

model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
history = model.fit(  x_train
                    , y_train
                    , epochs = epoch_to_train
                    , batch_size = batch_size_to_train
                    , validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size_to_train, verbose=1)

predicted = model.predict(x_test, verbose=1)
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 7, 7)              252       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 7, 7)              420       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 7, 7)              420       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 7)                 420       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 7)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 24        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,536
Trainable params: 1,536
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 3879 samples, validate on 1663 samples
Epoch 1/100
3879/3879 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.0640 - acc: 0.4029 - val_loss: 1.0858 - val_acc: 0.4011
Epoch 2/100
3879/3879 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.0607 - acc: 0.3942 - val_loss: 1.0877 - val_acc: 0.4011
Epoch 3/100
...
Epoch 100/100
3879/3879 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.0543 - acc: 0.4112 - val_loss: 1.0880 - val_acc: 0.4011

1376/1663 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s
Model evaluation for T Score=[1.0879698376016165, 0.4010823809878337]
```

```
Start prediction...
1440/1663 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0

Predicted

(1663, 3)
[[0.374 0.305 0.322]
 [0.374 0.305 0.322]
 [0.374 0.305 0.322]
 ...
 [0.374 0.305 0.321]
 [0.374 0.305 0.321]
 [0.374 0.305 0.321]]

Y_test len=1663
Y_test shape=(1663, 3)
Y_test after reshape shape=(1663, 3)

Y_test and predicted result I've saved to csv table and this is the first 20 records

c1    c2   c3        pred_c1            pred_c2            pred_c3
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3736170828342438,0.3046604096889496,0.32172250747680664
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3736182451248169,0.30466771125793457,0.32171404361724854
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3736218512058258,0.304688423871994,0.32168975472450256
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3736271560192108,0.3047129809856415,0.3216598629951477
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.37367793917655945,0.3045872747898102,0.32173481583595276
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.3737723231315613,0.30433595180511475,0.321891725063324
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3739013969898224,0.3039909899234772,0.32210761308670044
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.3740204870700836,0.30357825756073,0.3224012553691864
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.37405434250831604,0.30318766832351685,0.3227579891681671
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.37375959753990173,0.3039003908634186,0.3223400115966797
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.37365707755088806,0.304235577583313,0.32210731506347656
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.37363600730895996,0.30434468388557434,0.3220193386077881
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.37363964319229126,0.30440154671669006,0.3219588100910187
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3736586272716522,0.30439913272857666,0.3219422399997711
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3736720085144043,0.3044174313545227,0.321910560131073
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.3737075924873352,0.30425700545310974,0.32203540205955505
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.37369728088378906,0.3042283356189728,0.32207438349723816
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.373714417219162,0.304155558347702,0.3221299946308136
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.3737255036830902,0.30413076281547546,0.3221437335014343
1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3737127482891083,0.30416059494018555,0.3221266567707062
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.37368619441986084,0.30419445037841797,0.3221193552017212
```

The question is - I think I do something wrong this the model archtecture. The results are too the same.
val_acc: 0.4011 almost aren't changing while learning process.

Answer (score 1):

Your model does not learn anything(would not say the model is at fault though).

In fact, given a "close-to-perfect" balance of the dataset, the random prediction probability in this case would be 33%. Yours is 40% (not perfectly balanced on the test set at least), although is is likely to predict only one class (as you can see in the test biased completely towards the first class).

You could try to use, for starting, a smaller learning rate (`0.0001` could be a starting point). There is virtually no difference between the results on the first epoch and the last one.

If this does not work, then increasing the "lag" could help perhaps(bigger frame would theoretically allow for capturing more information).

If this still does not work, it is likely that you need to work on the dataset/prepare it more (adding new features is a possibility?).

In general if the aforementioned really do not work at all, then it is time to take a step back and think if you framed the problem correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried make a learning rate smaller and bigger history lag but the picture is learning almost the same. May be need other model of data.  It is interesting because if I turn the task to regression approach the data works pretty well. But classification not. I think now take a well known classification problem (like Iris classification and run through my nn and check the results. If the results will be good the problem with my data if not something wrong with the network.

Comment: Thank you. If my answer helped you, could you be so kind as to upvote it? I do not expect to "accept" it since unfortunately your problem could not be solved with smaller LR and bigger frame.